# Cordova plugin malfunction

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am developing an Ionic application using ngCordova for the multiple plugins that access the phone features.

I encountered an issue a few days ago, it goes as follows:

I was cleaning up my platforms/android/ folder and accidentally removed the file used by the facebook plugin (https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin) called facebookconnect.xml

Being a good developer and using git, I retrieved it from my previous commits and added again to its respective location.

But, when after building and deploying my app on my test phone (Galaxy S3), I noticed that all the plugins that were installed were no longer functional (splashscreen, facebook, device, etc..) 
I tried reinstalling the plugins, removing them and installing them, but nothing worked. Until I removed the whole android project folder and added it again from scratch, install the plugins as well.

It seems that altering any file related to the plugins causes them to not work anymore

Does anyone have any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Cordova via the command line interface?

Assuming that you are...

What plugins are listed when calling:

```
cordova plugins list
```

If the plugins that no longer work are somehow listed there, try removing the plugins using:

```
cordova plugin rm [plugin namespace]
```

...and add them again.

If that doesn't work, you might have to manually edit the plugins/[platform].json file (e.g. plugins/android.json) to fix some missing info there.

Comment: I tried that, the plugins show normally when running 'list' but removing and reinstalling doesn't help, they still give undefined.

Comment: Which platform are you building for? Did you refer to cordova.js in your HTML page? Does your code wait for the onDeviceReady event to fire?

Comment: Yes all that is available. everything is concatinated into one js file and i am using $ionicPlatformReady to wait for the device ready and call the plugins. This setup works fine it's already been tested, but as soon as something changes in a file related to the plugins it's like theyre not install anymore